# Cache issue - Refresh page (F5 button) to see modified content

Tags: php, caching, yii2, browser-cache, http-caching

I’m using FileCache in my cache component. In my controller, I’m using :

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\filters\HttpCache',
    'only' => ['view'],
    'etagSeed' => function ($action, $params) {
        $model = $this->findModel(Yii::$app->request->get("id"));
        return $model->update_time;
    },
],
```

With `etagSeed` and/or `lastModified` I got the same behavior issue:

The cache works well with `yii\filters\PageCache` and `yii\filters\HttpCache`. But when the cache is invalidated (for example after updating the page), I still see the old cached content.
So when I'm visiting the target page from other page, I'm getting the old content. But when I push F5, the page refreshs with the last content.

I've checked the Etag value on my GET request in the browser, and I've found that I'm getting the old Etag value until I refresh the page using the F5 button.

This can be a standard browser behavior when using HttpCache ? But how can I see the new content without refreshing each time the browser to get the last content ?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Did you checked my answer? Did it work? If yes, please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PageCache and dependency in your controller. Note, that if your page is public, you should be prepared probably to accept an empty ID.

```
public function behaviors()
{   
    return [
        'viewCache' => [
            'class' => 'backend\components\filters\PageCache',
            'only' => ['view'],
            'duration' => 86400,    // 1 day 
            'variations' => [
                $_GET['id'] ?? null,
            ],  
            'dependency' => [
                'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
                'sql' => 'SELECT update_time FROM my_table WHERE id = :id',
                'params' => [
                    ':id' => $_GET['id'] ?? null,
                ]   
            ]   
            'enabled' => [
                isset($_GET['id']),
            ],  
        ],  
    ];  
}
```

Comment: With `yii\filters\PageCache`, the cache seems to be working. Thanks for your code @Tibor Nagy.

But, is there any solution for `yii\filters\HttpCache` ?